# How to Drag & Drop a link from another window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How can I drop a link (show the text of a link) in a div element if I drag the link from another tab in the web browser?

In the  section I've tried:

```
function drop(ev)
{ 
    ev.preventDefault();
    var data=ev.dataTransfer.getData("Text");
    ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}
```

but this doesn't work, as I expected.

Thanks

Comment: You want to get the URL of the link? If yes, you shouldn't be using getElementById

Comment: What do you mean by show the text of a link? Is it show the URL or show the a tag?

Comment: @LostInComputer I believe that he want's to show a text following the mouse pointer.

Comment: Tom we had a answer here that show this link (http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop), then I open two windows and try to drag from the first window and drop to the second one, and **this works** please try out this sample.